# What is the difference between thickness and heavy or over-concentrated stones?

Tags: go, thickness, influence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between thickness and heavy stones?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/what-is-the-difference-between-thickness-and-heavy-stones)

Many beginners and even advanced players have difficulties telling apart thick from heavy or over-concentrated groups. How are these terms defined, and how can I quickly decide if a result in a certain position is good or bad for me based on that?

Is influence the same as thickness, or is there a difference?